# android Transform Exception

Tags: android, exception, transform

I get the following exception when I tried to run my project on a device with Kitkat O.S. I am not sure what this error is.It workes perfectly on lollipop device.

Exception:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            apply plugin: 'maven'

        }

    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile project(':payUMoneysdk')
}
```

Comment: Do you have volley jar file as well in libs folder?

Comment: I have payement gateway integration library. It uses Volley in its build.gradle

Comment: Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes that is the reason.

Comment: So please tell me how to solve it

Comment: I tried removing the volley dependency in the build.gradle, but it shows error

Comment: From which build.gradle your projects or from payUMoneysdk's?

Comment: payuMoneney sdk's

Comment: Try removing it from your projects build.gradle.

Comment: It worked.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have volley library in one of your dependencies.

Remove the following line from your `build.gradle`.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```